# Why can't i use the $http service in a route resolve?

Tags: angularjs

I want to make my views show only after the initial data is fetched and i am trying to accomplish this with a route resolve, but i can't get it to work. What am i doing wrong? Also my angular skills are a bit shabby so i aplogize in advance if my question is dumb.

Application.js :

```
var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', ['ngRoute']);

Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');

        $routeProvider

            .when('/packing/scan.html', {
                templateUrl: 'packing/scan.html',
                controller: 'PackingScanController',
                resolve: {
                    initData : Application.PackingScanInit()
                }
            })

            .when('/packing/stats.html', {
                templateUrl: 'packing/stats.html',
                controller: 'PackingStatisticsController'
            })

            etc
```

and here is my Scan.js file :

```
Application.PackingScanInit = function ($q,$timeout,$http) {

    var serverData = "";

    $http.get('/packing/scan.action')
        .success(function(data){
            serverData = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            serverData = data;
        });

    return serverData;

}

Application.controller('PackingScanController', ['initData', '$scope', '$http', function(initData, $scope, $http) {

    var packer = this;

    // Message log model
    packer.messageLog = [{
        status : "",
        message : null      
    }];
```

the files are included in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.PackingScanInit = function ($q,$timeout,$http) {

    return $http.get('/packing/scan.action')
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            return data;
        });

}
```

Also you have to adjust your resolve to this:

```
   resolve: {
                initData : Application.PackingScanInit
            }
```

Here is a specific working example:

```
(function() {

  angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

  function TestCtrl($scope, initData) {
    $scope.value = initData;
  }

  angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      template: '`<p>Dude {{value}}</p>`',
      controller: TestCtrl,
      resolve: {
        initData: function($http) {

          return $http.get('test.json')  //change to test-e.json to test error case
            .then(function(resp) {
              return resp.data.value;  //success response
            }, function() {
              return 'Not Found';  // error response
            });

        }
      }
    });
  });

})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SPR3jLshcpafrALr4qZN?p=preview

Comment: still no dice, it gives me this error

Unknown provider: initDataProvider <- initData <- PackingScanController

Comment: hhmmm try just copy pasting the ```Application.PackingScanInit``` function directly into the resolve.  I am wondering if the function isn't defined at the time the config is run.

Comment: well, you are right about that, the scripts are loaded in this order, so i first declare the app with the config, then the function and only after that the controller. but that still doesn't solve the error :/

Comment: I created a working plnkr.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

service are singletons means there are initialized only one but time but if you simply return from service it will be called one time but if you return a function from service it will be called again and again .See Below Sample for working.

```
var app = angular.module('ajay.singhApp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            myVar: function (repoService) {
                return repoService.getItems().then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
      })
        .when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/view1'
      });
  }]);


app.factory('repoService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getItems: function () {
            return $http.get('TextFile.txt');
        }
    };
});
```